# Unable to set image to android gridview.setEmptyView

Tags: android

I have written a `grid view` that is working fine.
I need an image when `gridview` is having no item.
I tried to add it like

```
gridView.setEmptyView((ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.empty));
```

empty.png is the image in the res/drawable

but `imageView` is not getting showed when `grid View` is empty.

The full code

```
oncreate

 setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listhabbit_ma);

        gridView.setEmptyView((ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.empty));
        habbitListAdapter = new HabbitListAdapter(AppManager.getHabbits());
        gridView.setAdapter(habbitListAdapter);
        habbitListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HabbitDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivityForResult(intent, habbit_delete);
```

main.xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/listhabbit_ma"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp">
    </GridView>
```

I am unable to figure out the error. Should I define a image view at the end of `main.xml`?

edit1 
full layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/user_profile"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.07">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_ma"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_ma"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:text="@string/repotation"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/listhabbit_ma"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp">
        </GridView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_habbit_button_ma"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/user_profile"
        android:onClick="onAddButtonClick"
        android:text="Add new Habbit"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `findViewById(R.drawable.empty)` will return `null`

Comment: i tried to add image as suggested by you .. but instead of adding an image whole sceen goes blue... only buttons are visible

Comment: there are no buttons at the `main.xml` layout you posted, please read carefully about layout system in Android.

Comment: i have posted the full layout

Comment: this view should be also attached to the tree view, please take a look on my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing it right. `Image` != `ImageView`. The proper way, for example, is the following (very simplified):

```
ImageView iView = new ImageView(mContext);
//set layout params if needed
iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);
((ViewGroup)gridView.getParent()).addView(iView);
gridView.setEmptyView(iView);
```

You can also declare it at your `XML` layout as @VipulPatel shown

Comment: @shivgarg yes, of course you can write simply `this` if we are talking about `Activity`

Comment: i have done the same..     ImageView im = new ImageView(this);
        im.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty);
        gridView.setEmptyView(im);    but instead of setting image whole screen goes blue and linear layout becomes weird

Comment: i know this is illogical to ask but i am unable to debug it

Answer (score 1):

Following layout and code works fine :

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <GridView
android:id="@+id/listhabbit_ma"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:numColumns="2"
android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:paddingBottom="3dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp">
</GridView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_list_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="List view is empty"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**Code :**

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById( R.id.listhabbit_ma );
TextView tvNoDataFound = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_list_view);
tvNoDataFound.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
gridView.setEmptyView( findViewById( R.id.empty_list_view ) );
```

Comment: `gridView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_list_view));` -> `gridView.setEmptyView(tvNoDataFound);`